# Matrix, basis, vector syntax

Tags: list-manipulation, syntax

I am in the beginning of learning tensors, basis and other linear algebra subjects and am having quite some difficulty using mathematica in regards creating such objects that mathematically work. Or to be more exact, *I* still haven't figured out how to *correctly* write such objects.

Mathematicas typical mathematical writing/syntax likiness fails for me it seems when using its array/lists form. This is surely because I can't figure it out, and not something the language is lacking in.

Typically when wanting to write a vector, or matrix one can do something like this:

```
matA = RandomInteger[1, {3, 3}];
vectorA = {1,2,3};
matB = {{1,0,0},{0,1,0},{0,0,1}};
```

Now, if I create two different basis, to create a transformation matrix, I do something like this:

```
basis1 = {{e1}, {e2}, {e3}};
basis2 = {{h1}, {h2}, {h3}};
```

I can multiply these:

```
basis1.Transpose[basis2]
```

$$\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 \text{e1} \text{h1} & \text{e1} \text{h2} & \text{e1} \text{h3} \\
 \text{e2} \text{h1} & \text{e2} \text{h2} & \text{e2} \text{h3} \\
 \text{e3} \text{h1} & \text{e3} \text{h2} & \text{e3} \text{h3} \\
\end{array}
\right)$$

and get a solution from what I read about...

If I give each $e_i$ and $h_j$ a specific value, such as:

```
e1 = {1, 0, 0};
e2 = {0, 1, 0};
e3 = {0, 0, 1};
h1 = {-1, 0, 0};
h2 = {0, 1, 0};
h3 = {0, 0, -1};
```

and now try to create a Directional cosine matrix, described as $A^{21}=basis2.basis1^T$

I continually get dimensional errors....though, if I flatten the lists beforehand

```
Flatten[basis1, 1].Flatten[Transpose[basis2], 1]
```

$$\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 -1 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 1 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & -1 \\
\end{array}
\right)$$

I get something I expect...However something tells me my syntax is simply incorrect...so to solve this and for all the others who are stumbling,

What is the correct way/syntax to write basis, vectors, matricies, so that one can perform basis operations on such objects for tensor calculationss or vector/base transformations in a symbolic way?

Comment: Mathematica doesn't have vectors, it has lists. Doing this `{{x},{y},{z}}` is pretty common for people who come from MATLAB. Just write `{x,y,z}`. See here: http://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/OperationsOnVectors.html _...The Wolfram Language represents vectors as lists, and never needs to distinguish between row and column cases..._

Comment: MMA does not use the column/rows paradigma, it does not distinguish between the two. Instead, if you have a.b (a and b may be vectors matrizes, tensors) the rule for index summation (contraction) is: the last index of a is summed over the first index of b

Comment: If an example that shows this is given of the transformations and etc in an answer I can gladly accept it.

Comment: @morbo there are many other questions on the subject, https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/search?q=column+vectors